# Changing links in my accordion menu plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there anyway I can change the links in this accordion drop menu to go from areas on the same page to an external HTML page. I have tried many different things but can't seem to do it without loosing my styles. Right now it is set up for a table of contents and links to specific areas on the same page.

Here is the code. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.
Mike

```
..................................
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div id="toc-holder" class="toc-holder">
    <a href="#" class="toc-link" id="toc-link"><span>▼</span> Table of Contents</a>
    <ul id="toc" class="toc">
      <li class="toc-h1"><a href="#section1">1. Loomings</a>
        <ul class="toc-sub closed">
          <li><a href="#section1-1">1.1 Call me Ishmael</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section1-2">1.2 Circumambulate</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="toc-h1">
        <a href="#section2">2. The Carpet-Bag</a>
        <ul class="toc-sub closed">
          <li><a href="#section2-1">2.1 I stuffed a shirt</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section2-2">2.2 As most young candidates</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="toc-h1">
        <a href="#section3">3. The Spouter-Inn</a>
        <ul class="toc-sub closed">
          <li><a href="#section3-1">3.1 Entering that gable-ended</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section3-2">3.2 But what most puzzled</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="toc-h1">
        <a href="#section4">4. Counterpane</a>
        <ul class="toc-sub closed">
          <li><a href="#section4-1">4.1 Upon waking next morning about daylight...</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section4-2">4.2 My sensations were strange</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="toc-h1">
        <a href="#section5">5. Breakfast</a>
        <ul class="toc-sub closed">
          <li><a href="#section5-1">5.1 I quickly followed suit</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section5-2">5.2 You could pretty plainly tell</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="toc-h1">
        <a href="#section6">6. The Street</a>
        <ul class="toc-sub closed">
          <li><a href="#section6-1">6.1 If I had been astonished at first</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section6-2">6.2 But, besides the Feegeeans</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.fixedTOC.js?v=3.0"></script>
<script>
// call the plugin on the "#toc" element
$('#toc').fixedTOC({
menuOpens: 'click', // or 'mouseenter'
scrollSpeed: 1000,
menuSpeed: 300,
useSubMenus: true,
resetSubMenus: true,
topLinkWorks: true
});
</script>
<script>
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-1965499-1']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function() {
  var ga = document.createElement('script');
  ga.type = 'text/javascript';
  ga.async = true;
  ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
</script></div>
</body>
........................................
```

Comment: Isn't this just a case of changing your <a href="#XXX" to <a href="http://www.google.com"?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change your `href`s in the `<a>` tags to external links (rather than the anchors with the # (hashtags).
Example below (or **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/cLgq7poz/)**):

```
<li><a href="http://jimulle.com">1.1 Call me Ishmael</a></li>
```

*note, we have no idea what `<script src="js/jquery.fixedTOC.js?v=3.0"></script>` does so if this doesn't work for you, you may need to share this script with us